# Mule 4 : Batch Processing : Error in Accept Expression in Batch step

Tags: mule, mule4

I am using Batch processing which has more than one batch steps.

The output of one batch step is :

```
[
  {
    "CustomerId": "00",
    "TotalPurchase": 0
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "11",
    "TotalPurchase": 1
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "22",
    "TotalPurchase": 8
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "33",
    "TotalPurchase": 27
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "44",
    "TotalPurchase": 64
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "55",
    "TotalPurchase": 125
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "66",
    "TotalPurchase": 216
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "77",
    "TotalPurchase": 343
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "88",
    "TotalPurchase": 512
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "99",
    "TotalPurchase": 729
  },
  {
    "CustomerId": "1010",
    "TotalPurchase": 1000
  }
]
```

In The next Batch step, I am using the ACCEPT EXPRESSION field with value as :

```
#[payload.TotalPurchase > 100]
```

But I am getting the error :

```
Types `Array` and `Number` can not be compared.
payload.TotalPurchase > 100
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to process each element of the array as a record but for that input payload the value of `#[payload.TotalPurchase]` is:

```
[
  0,
  1,
  8,
  27,
  64,
  125,
  216,
  343,
  512,
  729,
  1000
]
```

That's because DataWeave returns an array of all TotalPurchase members in the array. So it is not possible to compare that computed array to a number.